# Why HTML5 support `dir` attribute?

Tags: html, css

I noticed that if I want to change the direction orders of my elements I should use dir attribute (e.g. `<div dir="ltr"></div>`).

I got surprised that HTML5 confirms this approach and does not replace it with CSS3 because as much as I know, the approach of HTML5/CSS3 is to put elements on the HTML file and style them with the CSS. That is why attributes such as `align`, `width` and `height` (except img tag for optimization and only in px) are deprecated. In addition, Removing styling tags such as `<font>` confirms this approach.

I am wondering why `dir` attribute is still in the HTML and not in the CSS? Is there any reason for it?

Comment: Screenreaders may use it.

Comment: @LuudJacobs I think screen-readers can access the css file because they do not read `visibility:hidden` elements.

Comment: You said it's not in the CSS. Not true, there is a direction in CSS: [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction),  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

Comment: `dir` is a property of the text. It’s not stylistic.

Comment: @makadlcik, It is in both CSS syntax and HTML attributes which makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the complete answer [here](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup)

> Because directionality is an integral part of the document structure,
>   markup should be used to set the directionality for a document or
>   chunk of information, or to identify places in the text where the
>   Unicode bidirectional algorithm alone is insufficient to achieve
>   desired directionality.
>
> To produce the desired right-to-left or bidirectional effect, some
>   people simply apply CSS to whatever general paragraph or inline
>   elements surround the relevant text. However, styling applied by CSS
>   is not permanent. It may be turned off, be overridden, go
>   unrecognised, or be changed/replaced in different contexts. The markup
>   may also find its way into places where the CSS is not available, eg.
>   via shared databases, or quoted fragments.
>
> Although bidi markup is only needed for the visual rendering of a text
>   it is not purely decorative in function.
>
> Markup remains integrated with the document content in a persistent
>   fashion. It also lends significant clarity to the content if you use
>   dedicated bidi markup. You should therefore use dedicated bidi markup
>   whenever it is available. Do not simply attach CSS styling to a
>   general element to achieve the effect.

That is why both `dir` attribute and css exists in HTML5.

Answer (score 4):

The direction of elements is a side effect. The attribute describes the direction the language is written in. For example, English is a left to right language while Hebrew is a right to left language. It is thus a semantic attribute.

Comment: That is interesting. What is the point of putting a semantic attribute in the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

If an attribute in HTML5 is not deprecated there's a reason for it, and this case is no exception. Firstly it's worth pointing out that there is a CSS [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/direction) property, so it does exist. But it's actually *better* to use the attribute, here's why:

(The following quotes are all from [w3](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup))

The `dir` attribute is used to set the base direction of text for display. It is essential for enabling HTML in right-to-left scripts.

> Use the dir attribute on a block element only when you need to change the base direction of content in that block. Do not use CSS.
>
> You should always use dedicated bidi markup to describe your content, where markup is available. Then CSS may or may not also be needed to describe the meaning of that markup.

More specifically:

> ...directionality is an integral part of the document structure [so] markup should be used ....
>   styling applied by CSS is not permanent. It may be turned off, be overridden, go unrecognised, or be changed/replaced in different contexts. Although bidi markup is only needed for the visual rendering of a text it is not purely decorative in function...

Essentially saying that it's more well recognised and you will achieve a more persistent result across browsers.

Personally, if you're using it purely for styling content (which is what CSS is designed for) then I wouldn't use the attribute. Mainly for the reason you're likely to use another property that limits your website's compatibility anyway, and most people use it for styling purposes instead of language support and whatnot. I consider it to be an accessibility feature because not everyone needs it, but it's good for it to be there for those who do.

---

It's worth pointing out there is also a third option of using paired Unicode bidi formatting code characters. However it is best to avoid this as it can become impractical, [w3 recognise this](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls#answer) too:

> When control characters are used in free-flowing content there is always a likelihood of overlapping or unterminated ranges
>
> It is also much easier to manage inheritance and the effects of paragraph separators with markup.
>
> The HTML 4 specification specifically warns against mixing the two approaches because of the increased likelihood of improper nesting.

---

I lied,  it's not an official accessibility feature, but I consider it as one. While the following is true:

> neither markup nor CSS should be used [`unless they are needed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/#ri20030726.132037950).

HTML5 adds a [new feature](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir#dirauto):

> HTML5 provides a new value for the dir attribute: auto. The auto value tells the browser to look at the first strongly typed character in the element. If it's a right-to-left typed character such as a Hebrew or Arabic letter, the element will get a direction of rtl. If it's, say, a Latin character, the direction will be ltr.

Essentially meaning that HTML5 will automatically select the best option. So it selects the corresponding value which suits the language the user is reading it in. Bear in mind that most browsers offer a translation service. By my definition this makes in an accessibility feature.

Comment: "I consider it to be an accessibility feature" 
I do not get this part. Could you provide a practical example for this attribute except than styling?

Comment: I appreciate your complete answer but I think it confirms my saying that "dir" should be a css style (as it is), but the "dir" attribute is redundant and unnecessary.